# submitting form via AJAX - Input values are empty

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which is submitted via AJAX. Everything works perfectly except only a few input values are always empty.

*NOTE: I'm only posting a snippet of my HTML (only the inputs in question) as it is too large to post all of it.*

**HTML**

```
<!-- This input gets submitted successfully-->
<p id="other_lang">
    <strong>Define the other languages you use?</strong>
    <input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio29_7' name='other'>
</p>

<!-- This input doesn't submit and are always empty-->
<p id="visualstudio"> 
    <strong>How many licenses do you have?</strong>
    <input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio77_8' name='lqvs'>
</p>

<!-- This input doesn't submit and are always empty-->
<p id="os"> 
    <strong>For which operating systems?</strong>
    <input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio77_9' name='lqos'>
</p>

<!-- This input doesn't submit and are always empty-->
<p id="ms"> 
    <strong>Would you be willing to explore building some aspects of your technology on the Microsoft platform?</strong>
    <input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio77_10' name='lqms'>
</p>
```

So `<input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio29_7' name='other'>` submits successfully but the other 3 inputs are always empty.

**JQUERY**

```
var langformData = {
    'lq1'  : $('input.lang:checked').serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]').replace(/%23/g, '#'),
    'lq2'  : $('input[name=lq2]:checked').val(),
    'lq3'  : $('input[name=lq3]:checked').val(),
    'lq4'  : $('input[name=lq4]:checked').val(),
    'lq5'  : $('input[name=lq5]:checked').val(),
    'lq6'  : $('input[name=lq6]:checked').val(),
    'lq7'  : $('input[name=lq7]:checked').val(),
    'lq8'  : $('input[name=lq8]:checked').val(),
    'lq9'  : $('input[name=other]').val(),
    'lq10' : $('input[name=lqvs]').val(),
    'lq11' : $('input[name=lqos]').val(),
    'lq12' : $('input[name=lqms]').val()
};

// process the form
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
    url     : 'lang_ajax.php', // the url where we want to POST
    data    : langformData, // our data object
    success : function() {
        console.dir (langformData);
    },
    error   : function() {
        console.log ('Error submitting');
    }
})
```

**Here is what I get in my Console:**

```
Object
    lq1: "lq1[]=Java&lq1[]=JavaScript&lq1[]=Other"
    lq2: "Yes"
    lq3: "Yes"
    lq4: "No"
    lq5: "Level 100 (Novice)"
    lq6: "Limited"
    lq7: "Level 200 (Intermediate)"
    lq8: "Limited"
    lq9: "Haskell"
    lq10: ""
    lq11: ""
    lq12: ""
```

Note that `lq10, lq11 and lq12` are empty.

I have tried giving the inputs a value, which didn't work. I have checked for syntax errors etc but nothing worked.

**UPDATE 1**

The inputs in question are hidden by using jquery `.hide()`. When a user checks one of the checkboxes, the input fades in using `.fadeIn()`. Could this be the cause of the data getting lost?

**UPDATE 2**

Here's a fiddle of how it basically works: http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/foon38az/

And here is a fiddle with my full JS file: http://jsfiddle.net/ggChris/ngpvozuh/

Basically I'm building a quiz where only one question is displayed at a time. When a user click on the button (its not a submit button), next question is displayed.

Not sure if the full JS file will help with the issue, because the data gets submitted fine, its only the some of the inputs that doesn't work.

**UPDATE 3**

Here's the complete HTML (including PHP):

```
<?php session_start();

require '../check_client_session.php';  
require_once '../conf/conf.php';


/* Select queries return a resultset */
$query  = "SELECT * FROM lang_questions";
$result = $con->query($query);

include 'lang_header.php';  
?>

<div class="block">

    <a class="logout" href="?logout=1">Log Out</a>

    <h1 class="h1">Applications & Languages</h1>  

    <span class="errors"></span>
    <form method='post' id='quiz_form'>
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>

        <div id="question_<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class='questions'>
        <h4 id="question_<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><span><?php echo "Q" . $row['id']. "."?></span><?php echo $row['question_name'];?></h4>

        <div class='align single-question <?php if ($row['class'] == "lang"){ echo 'col-6';} ?>'>
        <p>
            <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php if ($row['class'] != "isv"){echo $row['answer1'];} else echo $string1; ?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
            <label class="labels" id='ans1_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio1_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer1'] ?></label>
        </p>
        <p class="<?php if (empty($row['answer2'])) echo 'hide'; ?>">
            <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer2'];?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio2_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
            <label class="labels" id='ans2_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio2_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer2'] ?></label>
        </p>
        <p class="<?php if (empty($row['answer3'])) echo 'hide'; ?>">
            <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer3'];?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio3_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
            <label class="labels" id='ans3_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio3_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer3'];?></label>
        </p>
        <p class="<?php if (empty($row['answer4'])) echo 'hide'; ?>">
            <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer4'];?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio4_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
            <label class="labels" id='ans4_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio4_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer4'];?></label>
        </p>
        <p id="visualstudio"> 
                <strong>How many licenses do you have?</strong>
                <input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio77_8' name='lqvs'>
        </p>
        <p id="os"> 
                <strong>For which operating systems?</strong>
                <input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio77_9' name='lqos'>
        </p>
        <p id="ms"> 
                <strong>Would you be willing to explore building some aspects of your technology on the Microsoft platform?</strong>
                <input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio77_10' name='lqms'>
        </p>
        <input type="radio" checked='checked' value="5" style='display:none' id='radio4_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['id'];?>'>
    </div>

    <?php if ($row['class'] == "lang"){ ?> 

        <div class='align single-question col-6 no-marginl'> 
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer5'] ?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio5_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans1_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio5_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer5'] ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer6']?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio6_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans2_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio6_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer6'] ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer7'];?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio7_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans3_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio7_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer7'];?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer8'];?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio8_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans4_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio8_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer8'];?></label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class='align single-question col-6'> 
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer9'] ?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio9_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans1_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio9_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer9'] ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer10']?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio10_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans2_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio10_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer10'] ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer11'];?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio11_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans3_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio11_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer11'];?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer12'];?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio12_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans4_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio12_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer12'];?></label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class='align single-question col-6 no-marginl'> 
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer13'] ?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio13_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans1_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio13_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer13'] ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer14']?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio14_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans2_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio14_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer14'] ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer15'];?>" class="rad <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio15_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans3_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio15_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer15'];?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="<?php echo $row['type'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['answer16'];?>" class="rad other_lang_option <?php if (!(empty($row['class']))) echo $row['class'] ?>" id='radio16_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['name'] ?>'>
                <label class="labels" id='ans3_<?php echo $row['id'];?>' for='radio16_<?php echo $row['id'];?>'><?php echo $row['answer16'];?></label>
            </p>
            <p id="other_lang">
                <strong>Define the other languages you use?</strong>
                <input type="text" value="" class="rad" id='radio29_7' name='other'>
            </p>
        </div>  

    <?php } ?>

    <br/>
    <input type="button" id='next<?php echo $row['id'];?>' value='Next' name='question' class='butt'/>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php }?>
</form>

<div id="errors" class="hide">
        <div id='error'></div> 
    </div>

<?php
/* free result set */
$result->free();

/* close connection */
$con->close();
?>

<div class="progress">
    <p>PROGRESS <span id="no_questions"></span></p>
    <div class="meter">
        <span id="inner-meter"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you build the object manually instead of using `form.serialize()`?

Comment: No not really :) just thought it would be easier to handle the inputs seperately in PHP

Comment: `'input[name="lqms"]' ` not `'input[name=lqms]'`

Comment: @madalinivascu — What's the point of adding those optional quote marks?

Comment: @madalinivascu I have tried that as well... no difference

Comment: I don't think there is enough code here to reproduce the problem. Can you try making a [live test case](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which shows the failure to collect the data?

Comment: $('input[name=lqms]') this gives you a list not a single object

Comment: Your codes working fine for me. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3cf7wjv9/3/).

Comment: @JoseRocha — It gives you a jQuery object. All jQuery objects have arrays under the hood. That won't stop `val()` from working.

Comment: i think the content or the inputs are dynamically created

Comment: @Chris I tried your code. The jquery did contain the data for lq10,11 and 12.

Comment: @Quentin , it not stop it but it will be a bad implementation, if other object has the same name it will always choose the first.

Comment: @JoseRocha — That would be one explanation, but there isn't enough code in the question to demonstrate that that is the problem.

Comment: I updated my answer... might be the cause of the issue?

Comment: @Chris can you tell us where the obj langformData is being fulfilled

Comment: @JoseRocha what do you mean by fullfill?

Comment: can you show the complete method and when it is called? like if it is on a submit button click?

Comment: @JoseRocha I updated my answer. Thanks for everyone's help so far!

Comment: can we have your html?

Comment: @madalinivascu I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var formData = {};
       $.each($(this).find('input'),function(i,v){
             formData[$(v).attr("name")] = $(v).val();
       });
       console.log(formData);       
   });
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uLjakuf/1/). Something must be wrong with the selectors you were using , although `.serialize()` is always the best solution for converting the form.

Answer (score -2):

Write this coed in jquery:

```
var langformData = {
    'lq1'  : $('input.lang:checked').serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]').replace(/%23/g, '#'),
    'lq2'  : $('input[name=lq2]:checked').val(),
    'lq3'  : $('input[name=lq3]:checked').val(),
    'lq4'  : $('input[name=lq4]:checked').val(),
    'lq5'  : $('input[name=lq5]:checked').val(),
    'lq6'  : $('input[name=lq6]:checked').val(),
    'lq7'  : $('input[name=lq7]:checked').val(),
    'lq8'  : $('input[name=lq8]:checked').val(),
    'lq9'  : $('input#radio29_7').val(),
    'lq10' : $('input#radio77_8').val(),
    'lq11' : $('input#radio77_9').val(),
    'lq12' : $('input#radio77_10').val()
};
```

Comment: Why use a input selector and a ID?